# Compiling java source code on linux

Tags: java, linux

I'm trying to compile my source code which divided into different packages.
i wrote a sources text and list inside it all the paths of the java files.
i also made a makefile and wrote the following lines:

```
compile: bin
    javac -d bin -cp biuoop-1.4.jar @sources.txt
run:
    java -cp biuoop-1.4.jar:bin Ass5Game 2 4
bin:
    mkdir bin
```

the biupoop is a built jar file i'm using.

after i use the make commend the computer says:

```
javac -d bin -cp biuoop-1.4.jar @sources.txt
javac: file not found: animations\Animation.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
make: *** [compile] Error 2.
```

how do i compile the files in packages?

Comment: What is the current directory you issue the call from and where are the sources relative to that location?

Comment: Why are you using makefiles for java? It works I guess but there are build tools such as maven and gradle (more https://github.com/tkruse/build-bench ) that make building java projects far simpler.

Comment: i'm in the user directory, and i have a "src" file which inside it there are couple of packages. for example one of the paths is "animations\Animation.java".

Comment: That \ seems a little strange to me as on Linux the path separator is `/`.

Comment: @zapl, i need to as part of my assignment.

Comment: ok, that's a legit reason

Comment: @TobiasBrösamle, i works on windows on the intellij, but the submitting is on the university server which is linux. so after i finished the assignment i upload it to my linux directory in the university server.

Comment: As mentioned by @T.J.Crowder in his answer, path separators on Linux systems are `/`, while on windows systems it's ``\``. Follow his answer to solve the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key is in this error message:

```
javac: file not found: animations\Animation.java
```

Note the backslash. On *nix, paths are separated with slash (`/`), not backslash (`\`). If you change the `\` in your `sources.txt` to `/` instead, it will work (assuming you're running this in the directory that `animation` is a subdirectory of).

Example run:

```
$ cat animation/Animation.java 
package animation;

public class Animation {
    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Success");
    }
}
$ cat sources.txt 
animation/Animation.java
$ javac -d bin @sources.txt
$ java -cp bin animation.Animation
Success
```

Comment: the problem was that i needed to add the following line:find src -name "*.java" > sources.txt on the makfile

Comment: @yairabr: Yup. That will, indirectly, do what I said above.